# Is ASP.NET MVC Built on top of IHttpAsyncHandler?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is ASP.NET MVC Built on top of [IHttpAsyncHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpasynchandler.aspx)? I'm implementing some web processing code and, for some reason end up building a kinda MVC framework. So, for that reason is the question, is ASP.NET controller choice mechanism built on top of that handler or is something more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) class not, the [AsyncController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.asynccontroller.aspx) class yes. So if you have some I/O intensive operations you could perform them in an [asynchronous controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).